# Does ChannelId change?

Tags: java, netty

I think I have observed ChannelId change for a channel over time. Is this normal behavior?

Here's why I think that:

I am programming a game server where connections last a long time. I want to reference Channels, so I wrap them in a Player object and map those with ChannelId.asLongText() as keys in a HashMap. Here is that HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, Player> players = new HashMap<String, Player>();

public void registerPlayer(Channel c, String name, String password) {
    Player p = new Player(c, name, password);
    players.put(c.id().asLongText(), p);

    try {
        Future<CredentialCheckResult> future = workerTasks.submit(new AuthenticateCredentialsTask(context.getDatabase().getConnection(), c.id().asLongText(), name, password));
        loginFutures.add(future);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] "+e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] Registered and added worker for logging in "+name+" ("+c.id().asLongText()+") \t\t total players = "+players.size());
}

public void unregisterPlayer(String id) {
    System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] Unregistering player ("+id+") \t\t total players = "+(players.size()-1));
    Player p = players.get(id);
    players.remove(id);

    if (p == null) {
        System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] P WAS NULL ("+id+") \t\t total players = "+players.size());
    }

    if (p.getChannel().isActive()) {
        p.getChannel().close();
    }
}
```

The register and unregister methods are run from a different thread, called GameEngine. The HashMap is touched only by this thread.

Here's what my ServerHandler looks like, bearing this in mind:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    GameEngine game = context.getGameService();
    Packet p = (Packet) msg;

    if (p instanceof NewConnectionPacket) {
        NewConnectionPacket packet = (NewConnectionPacket) msg;
        game.queueLogic(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                game.registerPlayer(ctx.channel(), packet.getUsername(), packet.getPassword());
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    context.getGameService().queueLogic(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            context.getGameService().unregisterPlayer(ctx.channel().id().asLongText());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] "+" Kicked for inactive channel: "+ctx.channel().id().asLongText());
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    System.err.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] "+cause.getMessage());
    ctx.close();
}
```

GameEngine.queueLogic(Runnable) is thread safe, and only queues the work for the GameEngine thread.

When I run the server and log in (using the same credials for all users) a few users, and rapidly drop their connection on the client side, the server can't seem to unregister the Player from the HashMap correctly, because the players.get(ChannelId.asLongText()) will return null.

Here are the logs from a session where this happens:

```
    May 21, 2018 10:33:23 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog 
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
May 21, 2018 10:33:23 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry 
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
[main] GameEngine starting up...
May 21, 2018 10:33:44 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1hge0wf9v10qklm1j8rb36|3b94d659, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge0wf9v10qklm1j8rb36|3b94d659, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlinerp, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {password=******, user=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
Mon May 21 22:33:44 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon May 21 22:33:44 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon May 21 22:33:44 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
[GameEngine] Registered and added worker for logging in mads (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000001-4b49379c0cc5629d-2b8fd125)          total players = 1
[pool-1-thread-1] Looking up SQL data on player mads
[pool-1-thread-1] Finished looking up SQL data on player mads, result was VERIFIED
[GameEngine] Logged in succesfully mads
[GameEngine] Registered and added worker for logging in mads (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000002-777e5a8cccc572e5-65acb968)          total players = 2
[pool-1-thread-1] Looking up SQL data on player mads
[pool-1-thread-1] Finished looking up SQL data on player mads, result was VERIFIED
[GameEngine] Logged in succesfully mads
[GameEngine] Registered and added worker for logging in mads (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000003-22a191d14cc5787b-f58eab6f)          total players = 3
[pool-1-thread-1] Looking up SQL data on player mads
[pool-1-thread-1] Finished looking up SQL data on player mads, result was VERIFIED
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-3]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000003-22a191d14cc5787b-f58eab6f
[GameEngine] Unregistering player (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000003-22a191d14cc5787b-f58eab6f)         total players = 2
Mon May 21 22:33:51 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon May 21 22:33:51 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mon May 21 22:33:51 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
[GameEngine] Registered and added worker for logging in mads (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000004-edfb71804cc58079-6c340605)          total players = 3
[pool-1-thread-1] Looking up SQL data on player mads
[pool-1-thread-1] Finished looking up SQL data on player mads, result was VERIFIED
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-5] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-5]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000005-50468ea44cc5825e-52f26a37
[GameEngine] Unregistering player (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000005-50468ea44cc5825e-52f26a37)         total players = 2
[GameEngine] P WAS NULL (cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000005-50468ea44cc5825e-52f26a37)       total players = 3
Exception in thread "GameEngine" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hydrozoa.onlinerp_server.game.GameEngine.unregisterPlayer(GameEngine.java:89)
    at com.hydrozoa.onlinerp_server.net.RPServerHandler$2.run(RPServerHandler.java:49)
    at com.hydrozoa.onlinerp_server.game.GameEngine.run(GameEngine.java:128)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-4] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-4]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000004-edfb71804cc58079-6c340605
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-6] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-6]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000006-c3bd154facc587a0-3ef4f4b5
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000009-066e3818acc592cb-5618df97
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-8] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-8]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000008-65235126acc58ed4-10dc8b8f
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-2]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-0000000a-6034ea9b2cc59711-5b48e9f0
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-7] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-7]  Kicked for inactive channel: cc2f71fffe2d38f4-0000287c-00000007-693ab465acc58a8a-8251ba2a
```

I have tried using the ChannelId object as a key as well. I feel like I'm at my wits end with this.

I'm using NioServerSocketChannel.class for the Server, and NioSocketChannel.class for the client.

How can I reference the Channels in a way that doesn't change over time?

By the way, I am using Netty 4.1.25 which is the newest I could of find as of today.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I made a mistake by trying to remove the Player object from the HashMap in all cases.

It was possible for a client to connect, and then idle (causing them to not be registered, as registration happens with a login packet), and finally disconnecting. Thats what was happening.

My bad.

All in all, the ChannelId seems safe to use, and it doesn't change over time as far as I can tell.